# How to localize pimcore?

Tags: pimcore

I need to localize `pimcore` .I have read the help on that, from the pimcore wiki:

http://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE/Website+Translations

But i don't get it(since i am a newbie to development or what ever it is i'm doing!!).
It says something about registering locale in php file named action.
it seems so complicated .
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is pretty easy to localize your website actually.

- First [add all languages](http://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE/Localization) you want to support, this is done in the admin panel by going to `Settings -> System`, expand "`Localization & Internationalization`" and there you will have textbox for adding languages. Enter all languages and the press "Save" at the bottom right.
  [image]
- Next step is to add the translations, this is done by opening the `Extras -> Translations -> Shared Translations` in the admin panel. Press the + at top to add a word or sentence used for translation, give it a name and then enter the translation for all chosen languages:
  [image]
- Time to code, in your view or layout files (for example: /website/views/scripts/default/default.php), where you want a translation add the following code:

  ```
  <?php echo $this->translate("hello"); ?>
  ```
- Set the language of the documents, this is done by opening a document in Pimcore admin, go to the tab "`Properties`", and on the right side there will be a language setting, select the language for this document and press "Save & Publish":
  [image]

Now when you navigate to this document (or look at the preview tab) you will see your translated word where you placed the translate code.

**Translate the Admin UI**

To translate the Admin UI, go to `Extras > Download System Languages` in Pimcore, and there press the "+" on the language you want to download. To add to those translations you go to: http://www.pimcore.org/en/community/translations. (Read more here: http://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE/Translations)

You then choose which language to use in the admin UI by going to `Settings -> System` and then expanding the "`General`" section, and there you will find "`Default Language in Admin-Interface:`".

Comment: thanks for your time and help.could you explain the third part of your answer"Time to code, in your view or layout files ..." .where should i exactly put the code??

Comment: let's say in the picture above  , i want to translate welcome tab and everything in it like edit and delete an so on... .in which file and where in that file should i put the <?php echo $this->translate(" "); ?>code?

Comment: This is if you want to translate your views, which is the pages your visitors will see (read this: http://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE/Quick+Start+Guide)
If you want to localize the Administration UI, you can download already done translations from Extras > Download System Languages. I added more about this in the answer.

Comment: thank you very much . i guess i can translate  parts of  pimcore that i want through the page   http://www.pimcore.org/en/community/translations that you introduced .